# reading partitioned json data in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a large data set of json files which is partitioned into runDate, familyNumber and groupNumber. I want to read the file into spark dataframe. How to do it efficiently.

```
path = /abc/
runDate=20240130101010
   familyNumber=10
       groupNumber=1
              part-0000*.json
              part-0001*.json
              part-0002*.json
              part-0003*.json
```

I am reading it by:

`df = spark.read.format("json").load("/abc/runDate=20240130101010")`

its not able to read the data. Is there anything I am missing here...

I tried with other option as well:

`df = spark.read.format("json").load("/abc/runDate=20240130101010/familyNumber=10/groupNumber=1/")`

but its asking for the schema, is schema is necessary to read the json data. Though it has nested data in it, but I wanted to read as it is.

**ENVIRONMENT USING: Azure Databricks and reading it from Azure Container.**

Comment: Have you tried `spark.read.format("json").load("/abc/runDate=20240130101010/*/*")`

Comment: Since the data volum is so huge, Its taking so much of time and hence wanted to read through the particular "familyNumber" and for a particular "groupNumber". Is there a way to read this way ?

Comment: I think `df = spark.read.format("json").load("/abc/runDate=20240130101010/familyNumber=10/groupNumber=1/")` should work; however, if the error message says that you need to provide the schema, it usually means that the spark engine is finding folders under the last directory (`groupNumber=1`) rather than json files. You can run `dbutils.fs.ls("abc/runDate=20240130101010/familyNumber=10/groupNumber=1/")` to list the content of the directory and confirm that you're attempting to read json files.